# Constructor/Destructor function not being called while calling by value or reference. Any way around it?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, destructor

I'm having trouble because of a feature of c++. after working with dynamic memory allocation, I always clear the heap(free store) because of obvious reasons. I do it with the destructor function. And sometime, allocate memory using the constructor. but after calling an object from another function(call by value), only the destructor works. I know that it's a good feature in many cases. But, it is  annoying while working with a lot of stand-alone functions. Any way around it,guys? Or, should i just use a member function to allocate and clear memory?

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test{
int *a;
public:
test(int x) {a=new int;
             *a=x;}
int geta(){return *a;}
 ~test(){delete a;}
};

int apow2(test t)
{
return ((t.geta())*(t.geta()));
}

int main()
{
test tst(10);
cout<<"\nA^2="<<apow2(tst);
//at this point, memory reference to 'a' doesn't exist
cout<<"\n"<<tst.geta();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pick up a book on C++ and learn the language systematically. Most of what you describe sounds completely confused.

Comment: [Perhaps one of these.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191)

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're missing the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: @KerrekSB I am learning c++ systematically. I'm sorry if my description sounded confusing. now that i have read it myself, it really is confusing :P .

Comment: @Mat thanks for referring to it.

Comment: @user2143094 Pretend that `new` never existed.  Now rewrite your class given that assumption.  See how easy it becomes now?  The point being is that you introduced `new` in one of the most inappropriate places -- all you require is an `int` member, not an `int *` member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having trouble because you did not implement the *copy constructor* and *copy assignment operator* for class `test`: [you did not abide by the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/560648).

But, good news! You don't need to. You can avoid *all* of this kerfuffle by storing an `int` instead of an `int*`:

```
class test
{
   int a;

public:
   test(int x)
     : a{x}
   {}
};
```

That's it! No dynamic allocation, no memory management, nothing. Just `test`, and an `int` that is assured to survive for precisely `test`'s lifetime. Perfect.

If you need dynamic allocation for reasons not stated in your question (whoops), then you should use a smart pointer to manage its lifetime for you:

```
class test
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> a;

public:
   test(int x)
     : a{new int(x)}
   {}

   int geta() { return *a; }
};
```

That's it! No memory management, nothing. Just `test`, and an `int*` whose pointee is assured to survive for precisely `test`'s lifetime. Perfect.